# Inserting many views into one layout without them overflowing to the end of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm looking for a way that I can dynamically add views into a layout (currently a LinearLayout) and that they won't overflow into the end of the screen and be hidden.

I can't use ScrollViews since it has to look like one sentence (It's a "fill the blanks" question).

I'm just looking for an idea on how to do this, not the code itself.

Thanks in advance, Shay.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Why not just append text in a simple TextView? and why not use a scrollview? if it gets too long you need to scroll. (esp if you want to support different sized devices)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak It's not only TextViews though, it's a mix of textviews and buttons. Why not scroll? because it's suppose to be a trivia question and it'll look weird if the user has to scroll to view the question.

Comment: i think you could do that using views with weights inside a linearlayout with     a match_parent as height (try it not sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using linear layout than use linear layout with weights:

For example:
You have a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and you have 2 ImageViews inside it and you want these ImageViews always to take equal space.

`<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">`

You can set the layout_weight of each ImageView to 1 and the weightSum in LinearLayout to 2 to achieve this.

`<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>`

This will work correctly for any device without overflow into the end of the screen and be hidden